# How can I make clicking on a QTreeView partially checked node uncheck the node?

Tags: qt, checkbox, treeview, tri-state-logic

I have a `QTreeView` populated by a `QAbstractItemModel` subclass, allowing leaf nodes to be checked by the user.  If a proper subset of the descendant leaf nodes of a non-leaf node are checked, then that node is partially checked (`Qt::CheckStateRole` is `Qt::PartiallyChecked`).

Currently if the user clicks on a partially checked node then the check state changes to `Qt::Checked`; I want it to clear the node instead (`Qt::Unchecked`).  Is there a way to customise this behaviour?  To control this with a `QCheckBox` I would override [`QAbstractButton::nextCheckState()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractbutton.html#nextCheckState), but I can't find anything similar for `QTreeView`.

Answer (score 1):

Implement desired behaviour in you model setData

```
bool QAbstractItemModel::setData ( const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole )

For Qt::CheckStateRole
```

So when you receive in value a Qt::PartiallyChecked. You traverse item childs to set to Qt::Unchecked, and also change current item.

Comment: `value` isn't `Qt::PartiallyChecked`, it's `Qt::Checked`.  That's the problem.

Comment: So, do it when you receive a `Qt::Checked`. What's the problem? If you need it, you can even access current state with data(index, role)

Comment: That doesn't distinguish between `setData` called from a mouse click (or pressing the space bar) and from another cause, where `Qt::Checked` is the wanted value.  Hoping there's a better way (what code calls `setData`)?

Comment: setData is called by delegate. Implementing a custom delegate is the other way to get what you want